# Why wmctrl doesn't work for certain windows?

Tags: compiz, window-manager, window, wmctrl

```
francisco@Ubuntu:~$ wmctrl -l
0x02600006  0 Ubuntu Área de trabalho
0x03c00002  0 Ubuntu XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x03c00005  0 Ubuntu unity-launcher
0x03c00008  0 Ubuntu unity-panel
0x03c0000b  0 Ubuntu unity-dash
0x03c0000c  0 Ubuntu Hud
0x046000b3  0 Ubuntu How to make a window aways on top? - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
0x0520000b  0    N/A Qt Creator
0x05002396  0 Ubuntu francisco@Ubuntu: ~
0x0540000b  0    N/A backlight
```

For windows that have the machine name column as `N/A` I'm unable to send `wmctrl` commands like `wmctrl -r "window name" -b add,above`. Why? (also, I don't know why these windows are different regarding the machine name column...)

My initial intent was to send such command to the `backlight` window, a frameless Qt application. Using the window system menu and checking the "Always On Top" works for the window though. I just like a programmatic means of doing the same.

Comment: Maybe wmctrl has some problem with qt windows? Or does it show other qt windows just fine?

Comment: @vasa1 currently I've checked only two Qt windows, as shown, both mine and Qt Creator window seems to suffer from same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's definitely a bug in `wmctrl`.
after digging around wmctrl code, it seems that the bug is in translating window name strings to the corresponding Window ID (or XID). so `wmctrl -r "window name" -b add,above` is not reliable.

as a workaround, use XID instead, i.e. `wmctrl -i -r window_id -b add,above`. in your case , `wmctrl -i -r 0x0520000b -b add,above` should work.

most window management facilities are implemented as X window Properties. you can view all the properties of a window by a command `-- xprop`.

**NOTE:**

1. Windows that have the machine name column as N/A. 
   the machine name property is `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE`. it's rarely used. and some GUI toolkits may not implement them.
   you can view a window's machine name property by run following command line and click the window

   ```
   shell> xprop | grep MACHINE
   ```
2. As for Always On Top, it's another property value `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE`.
   to check it yourself, 
   run following command line and click the window

   ```
   shell> xprop | grep _NET_WM_STATE
   ```

Comment: sadly, I've already tried using id instead of window name, but the property is not being set by wmctrl.

Comment: I tested on qt-assistant and it worked when I used windo id. xprop also showed _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE. can you give me the output of xprop and xwininfo for the window you tested on?

Comment: thanks for the help, these are xprop and xwininfo for the Qt Creator window and for the nautilus home window: https://gist.github.com/oblitum/8126736.

Comment: I've tried `wmctrl -ri window_id -b add,above` both on Qt Creator window as on nautilus window, both it didn't work for none.

Comment: THANKS man, that was it, the thing is that, `wmctrl -ri` was not working here, then I changed it to pass flags more explicitly with `wmctrl -i -r <window id> -b add,above` and it's working now =) for all windows. Before, it was working for all but Qt windows, passing the window name.

Comment: please, just update the answer to pass the flags as I've done.

Comment: @sgxq, I've created a somewhat duplicated question at stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733215). I have a +500 reputation bounty there, if you care, you may also put an answer there, I'll give you the bounty. I don't have enough reputation here for a nice bounty.

Comment: `wmctrl -ir` is also working.

Comment: yeah, you're right. i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and comments.  After using hex win IDs the problems are gone :)

Comment: Someone should report the bug to `wmctrl` ...?