# Skype pop up video hack (forcibly resize window)

Tags: skype, wmctrl

I use Skype a lot, and a problem I face is that the video pop up doesn't come in ubuntu, as it does in Windows. I tried to use `wmctrl` for the desired results. This is what I did:

```
wmctrl -i -r ID -b add,above        #Bring Skype window on top
wmctrl -i -r ID -e 0,30,30,30,30    #Try to resize it to a small size
```

Where ID is the hex ID I got from doing `wmctrl -l`.

The first step above works fine. But in the second step, I am unable to shrink the window after a certain limit. Is there a way to force resize the window?

I am using Skype version `5.5.0.1` on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and a solution to solve the problem by somehow fixing Skype's feature of video pop up (that works on Windows) would also be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm fine even if the window is "cut" in a way that only the video part of Skype window is visible, as long as it can be restored to its previous state when done. The resize is so that Skype doesn't block too much of the rest of the screen.

EDIT 2: Here is the output of my wmctrl -v commands:

```
utkarsh@utkarsh-Inspiron-7537:~$ wmctrl -v -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
envir_utf8: 1
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Using window: 0x05600001
State 2: _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ
State 1: _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT
utkarsh@utkarsh-Inspiron-7537:~$ wmctrl -v -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -b add,above
envir_utf8: 1
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Using window: 0x05600001
State 1: _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
utkarsh@utkarsh-Inspiron-7537:~$ wmctrl -v -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -e 0,50,50,200,200
envir_utf8: 1
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Using window: 0x05600001
grflags: 3840
utkarsh@utkarsh-Inspiron-7537:~$ wmctrl -v -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -e 0,50,50,200,100
envir_utf8: 1
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Using window: 0x05600001
grflags: 3840
utkarsh@utkarsh-Inspiron-7537:~$
```

There was no difference in the window size between the last and second last command.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
wmctrl -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
xdotool search "Skype for Linux Beta" windowraise windowmove 50 50 windowsize 200 200
```

or

```
wmctrl -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -b add,above
wmctrl -r "Skype for Linux Beta" -e 0,50,50,200,200
```

do the trick.

Apparently the resizing – using either `wmctrl` or `xdotool` – doesn't work unless the window properties `maximized_vert` and `maximized_horz` are removed first. I generally prefer `xdotool` because of its well-written [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdotool.1.html), the many many options and the clear syntax, but it seems like only `wmctrl` is able to cope with those properties. Using `xdotool` however you can save one command call.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm unable to resize even after removing maximized_vert,maximized_horz. I tried wmctrl -v, bu the verbose output is not very helpful. Did it work for you?

Comment: @stranger_anon I tested a lot until I finally got this solution, so yes, for me with Skype for Linux Beta 5.5.0.1 this works flawlessly. Please add the full output of the three `wmctrl` lines run with the `-v` option to your question for me to investigate.

Comment: @stranger_anon Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394998/why-wmctrl-doesnt-work-for-certain-windows), please try again using `-ir ID` instead of using the window name, exactly like you did before.

Comment: Tried that. Still doesn't work. The output with "-v" is the same, except the WM_NAME errors are gone.

Comment: @stranger_anon That's really strange. I get the exact same output (with a different window ID of course) like you with those commands, but for me the window gets properly resized and positioned. I'm left speechless… :(